# Compile files with references to each other in Scala

Tags: scala

This is my first day of programming Scala and I need to build a project.

So, let's say I have one file `Config.scala`, which contains line `var BestPage1:BasePage = null` and another file `BasePage.scala`, which contains `if(m_Refer != null) m_Refer.mkString(Config.ReferSmallDivisor) else ""`.

And when I try to compile one of them, I get an `error: not found: value Config` or `error: not found: value BasePage`.

So how do I compile them both?

**ADDED: file contents**

[BasePage.scala](http://pastie.org/private/hdmtrcctqim8i4xkzufvq)

[Config.scala](http://pastie.org/private/actpl8chmgng3m2jwtuxoq)

Comment: Please, add full content of both files.

Comment: You have not accepted any of your answers. Please do them ese it gets discouraging to answer

Comment: Any of the answers did not resolve a problem. I used Intellij IDEA instead of command line and had no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `Config` in `package scwikimetric` and `BasePage.scala` in default package.

So either change package declararation in `BasePage.scala` to `package scwikimetric`. Or add an `import scwikimetric.Config` in `BasePage.scala`.

Comment: Does your BasePage contain any class inside?

Comment: BasePage is a class, and Config is an object.

Comment: Sorry I can't, they're too big.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not finding `Config` is because the `Config` class doesn't exist.

The `scwikimetric.Config` class, however, does. Import it and things will go much better, I think.

Comment: I added `import scwikimetric.Config` and now I get `object Config is not a member of package scwikimetric`

Comment: Did you move `Config.scala` to a `scwikimetric` subdirectory and try running `scalac BasePage.scala scwikimetric/Config.scala` ?

Comment: Yes, I did and it helped. But when I have more than two files, I get the same errors when using something like `scalac scwikimetric/*.scala` (with an asterisk).

Comment: Well, the problem is clearly linked to the fact that you don't quite understand how packages work yet and are trying things without really understanding their purposes. I suggest you read up on Scala packages - if you haven't yet, get [this book](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala), it's an amazing resource even if sometimes a bit hard to follow.